# Lookarounds with lazy quantifiers

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use a lookbehind followed by a lazy "match everything pattern" `(.+?)` in a regex, but I'm wondering if I can use lookarounds this way.

For example, I have the following regex : `(?<!learn).+?write a regex`

- `"I'm learning how to write a regex"` **(should not match)**
- `"I know how to write a regex"` **(should match)**
- `"I know how to read an write a regex"` **(should match)**
- `"I want to know how to write a regex"` **(should match)**
- `"I want to learn how to write a regex"` **(should not match)**

If you use the regex above, you get everything matched.

Comment: Everything  matches because regex is finding ANY string to the left of `write a regex` that does not match `learn`.  So, in your first example, `I'm l` does not match learn, so that negative lookbehind is TRUE,  then `earning how to ` matches `.+?n`, and  `write a regex` matches the end.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... So I can't use a lookbehind followed by a FIND ANY pattern :/

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple way to say "contains X, but does not contain Y".  Of course in Python you can test the same string twice...

Comment: a negative lookahead anchored at the start can be used `^(?!.*learn).*write a regex` may be used, otherwise another solution is to match first the not wanted pattern in an alternative : `(learn.*write a regex)|write a regex` and do a no-op if 1st group is captured. Because of how backtracking works, alternative parts are checked sequentially

Comment: @Chris Maurer Yeah, I did that, but it was really painful to measure the precision of my regexes that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern matches all lines, because `(?<!learn).+?write a regex` will run the lookbehind at the first position, asserting what is directly to the left of the current position is not `learn`

That assertions is true and this part will immediately match until the first occurrence of `write a regex`

What you can do, is make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) which supports an infinite quantifier in the lookbehind:

```
(?<!\blearn.+?)\bwrite a regex\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJk78o/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##jdC9DsIgEMDx/Z7iZLGNTRc3o@nsM1gHqrQl6kGOS6pPX@mHg4kmvRF@fwL4l7SOtn1vH96xIJvGPAG8FjFMeEBWSbFfldXdaKZ8U6Rl1bEVg3qyZaUAgrClJkR@AoyjjusHjkVcxtZ1KA6/MpXNEG8Ut5cTNvqKmv7RTpMMbMGpHzre87eFM0DtGANawvmRu7G39UTyEOtLm8wflmFIJzCMj4EkIe37Nw)

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?<!\blearn.+?)\bwrite a regex\b"

strings = [
    "I'm learning how to write a regex",
    "I know how to write a regex",
    "I know how to read an write a regex",
    "I want to know how to write a regex",
    "I want to learn how to write a regex"
]

for s in strings:
    if regex.search(pattern, s):
        print(s)
```

Output

```
I know how to write a regex
I know how to read an write a regex
I want to know how to write a regex
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this package, this is so helpful !

I looked at the docs, but I'm not quite sure about whether you can use conditional operators in lookarounds as well. I'm thinking about something like that :

`r"(?<!\blearn|want.+?)\bwrite a regex\b"`

Comment: @RomainM Do you mean like this? `(?<!\b(?:learn|want).+?)\bwrite a regex\b` https://regex101.com/r/2cf7eq/1 The alternation should be grouped if the `.*?` should apply to both words.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I was wondering why it wasn't working without grouping the conditional pattern lol... Thanks so much !